# repaint() not calling PaintComponent to use Graphics2D

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage, graphics2d, paintcomponent

I have spent a few days now trying to get the Graphics2D class to work within my code. I have it structured in such a way that when a click event is registered the call to repaint is done, however this only produces a nullpointer exception when it reaches the stage of calling repaint().

It is all working as expected when debugging and not called from within the paintComponent method, however when trying to call the code properly using paintComponent and repaint() to allow the Graphics2D class to display the lines to each point, It's not working.

I have included the parts of my code that I am having difficulty getting to work. Any help whatsoever will really be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Below is the GUI class that incldes my mouseListener.

```
public class GUI extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

private JLabel label;

    public BufferedImage getImg() {
    return img;
    }

    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    label = new JLabel();

    //set point equal to the location of the mouse click on the image label
    Point b = e.getPoint();

    //place we are going to print the dots
    segmentation.x = b.x; //gets the x coordinate 
    segmentation.y = b.y; //gets the y coordinate

    System.out.println("x = " + segmentation.x);
    System.out.println("y = " + segmentation.y);        

    //set the global img in the segmentation class equal to that of the one in the current tab
    segmentation.setImg(tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex(), getImg());
    segmentation.paintUpdate();
    label = segmentation.getLabel();

    //if i run this line of code the existing label I already have with simply vanish because of the paintComponent method not being called upon properly.
    //tabbedPane.setComponentAt(tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex(), label);
}
```

This is the Segmentation class that includes the paintComponent method that I am having trouble calling upon properly.

```
public class Segmentation extends JLabel {

public int[] xpoints = new int[50];
public int[] ypoints = new int[50];
private int npoints = 0;
public int x;
public int y;
GeneralPath polyline;
Graphics2D g2;
JLabel label;
BufferedImage img;
ImageIcon icon;

public void paintUpdate() {
    repaint();
}

public void setImg(int tabNum, BufferedImage img) {
    this.img = img;
}

public GeneralPath createPath() {

    //      if (npoints > 0) {
    polyline.moveTo(xpoints[0], ypoints[0]);

    for(int i = 1; i < xpoints.length; i++) {
        //add the position of the point to the respective x and y arrays
        polyline.lineTo(xpoints[i], ypoints[i]);        
    }
    //      }
    return polyline;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    System.out.println("we're in the paint component method");

    //set up for the new jlabel
    label = new JLabel();
    label.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(img));
    label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
    label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);

    //add the position of the point to the respective x and y arrays
    xpoints[npoints] = x;
    ypoints[npoints] = y;

    if (npoints == 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your first point has been added successfully");
    }
    else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your " + npoints + " rd/th" + " point has been added successfully");
    }

    polyline = createPath();

    // Draws the buffered image to the screen.
    g2.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);

    g2.draw(polyline);

    npoints++;
}
```

Comment: Why not you typcasted Graphics object to Graphics2D object within paintComponent method? g2 is never initialized in your code.

Comment: @VishalK makes an excellent point. You are not using g2 correctly, and in fact you would benefit greatly to reading tutorials on Swing graphics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Segmentation class has two JLabels, one the object of the class itself, which has a paintComponent override and is likely never used:

```
public class Segmentation extends JLabel {
```

and the other a JLabel called label which is held by composition in the class which doesn't have the method override which is in fact used and appears to be "shadowing" the class's instance:

```
JLabel label
```

If you want paintComponent to be called, you'll need to use the label object that in fact overrides that method.

Also you appear to be creating components within the `paintComponent(...)` method (??). Never do that nor have program logic within this method.

Edit:
To draw on an image, I usually override paintComponent and draw with its Graphics/Graphics2D object. For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DrawOnLabel extends JLabel {
   public static final String GIRAFFE_IMG_URL = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb" +
        "/9/9e/Giraffe_Mikumi_National_Park.jpg/474px-Giraffe_Mikumi_National_Park.jpg";
   private static final Color LINES_COLOR = Color.red;
   private static final Color CURRENT_LINE_COLOR = new Color(255, 200, 200);
   private List<Line2D> lineList = new ArrayList<Line2D>();
   private Line2D currentLine = null;

   public DrawOnLabel() throws IOException {
      URL giraffeUrl = new URL(GIRAFFE_IMG_URL);
      BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(giraffeUrl);
      ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
      setIcon(icon);

      MyMouseAdapter myMouseAdapter = new MyMouseAdapter();
      addMouseListener(myMouseAdapter);
      addMouseMotionListener(myMouseAdapter);
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

      g2.setColor(LINES_COLOR);
      for (Line2D line : lineList) {
         g2.draw(line);
      }
      if (currentLine != null) {
         g2.setColor(CURRENT_LINE_COLOR);
         g2.draw(currentLine);
      }
   }

   private class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
      Point p1 = null;

      @Override
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
         p1 = e.getPoint();
      }

      @Override
      public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
         if (currentLine != null) {
            currentLine = new Line2D.Double(p1, e.getPoint());
            lineList.add(currentLine);
            currentLine = null;
            p1 = null;
            repaint();
         }
      }

      @Override
      public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
         if (p1 != null) {
            currentLine = new Line2D.Double(p1, e.getPoint());
            repaint();
         }

      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      DrawOnLabel mainPanel = null;
      try {
         mainPanel = new DrawOnLabel();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.exit(-1);
      }

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("DrawOnLabel");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.setResizable(false);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, However I'm a bit unsure with how I would use the label object that overrides the paintComponent method. Sorry if this is a bit of a silly question.

Comment: @MrBillyUK: You need to get rid of the label variable and the `getLabel()` method inside the Segmentation class. And then create a Segmentation instance and use it as a JLabel in your other class. But again, there should be no program logic inside of `paintComponent(...)` and again you should cast the Graphics object in this method to Graphics2D and use it there.

Comment: I have already included an instance of the Segmentation class (it's how I call upon methods from the Segmentation class from within GUI class) globally from within the GUI class but forgot to include it in this example, apologies.

However I am a little unclear about what you mean by using the instance of Segmentation as a JLabel from within the GUI class. Is there any way you would be able to give me an example of how I could do this? Thanks again for everything.

Comment: @MrBillyUK: I'm sure that you do have an instance, but where do you place this instance in your GUI?

Comment: I declare it globally so that a new instance of it isn't called each time a new mouseEvent is triggered.

Comment: @MrBilly: I'm not sure of the logic of your program, so I can't fully speak for how you should use this class, but if you want to use it as a substitute for JLabel, then you should create an instance and place it in the GUI anywhere you would need it. However you may wish to tell you more about what overall problems you're trying to solve as the solution may be entirely different from what you're doing.

Comment: I was just wondering how I could call Segmentations paintComponent method from within the GUI class mostly. I removed the label variables along with the getLabel() method as you suggested but am still unable to call the paintComponent method as the way I am trying at the moment is through the paintUpdate() method that I have created within the Segmentation class which then calls repaint() only this isn't working for me.

Comment: @MrBillyUK: I think that we may be talking past each other. I'm not asking so much about what you're trying to do on a low-level, i.e., call this method or that, but rather what you're trying to do on a higher level, i.e., have the GUI show this or that to the user based on such and such event. Can you give us more information about your higher level goals?

Comment: sure, I'm trying to allow the user to select points on a Buffered image using mouse clicks to detect the x and y coordinates. However I want the x and y coordinates to have Graphics2D display a line between them at each step. Meaning rewriting the x and y coordinates stored within arrays each time the mouse listener is triggered. The BufferedImage is contained within a JLabel and that's why I was originally trying to create a new label from within the Segmentation class and later retrieve it back to the GUI class using a getLabel() method so that I could display it to you user.

Comment: @MrBillyUK: I have to run, but I've posted a brief example of what I've done for a similar situation.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I also have to run but I'm sure with everything you've said I'll be able to get it working. Thanks again for everything, it's very much appreciated.