# Trace a line above an image on JFrame Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have the fallowing code:

```
// set up the GUI for display the PgmImage object
    JFrame f = new JFrame("PGM Image:");
    f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });     
    f.add(this.drawImage);      
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
```

That produces this image:[image: PGM image on JFrame]

I wonder if it's possible to draw a line above the image on the same JFrame.
I have the discover a path with A* algorithm and trace it in this image.

Cumps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask:

> I wonder if it's possible to draw a line above the image on the same JFrame.

- Yes it's possible.
- As with most all Swing graphics, you wouldn't draw directly in the JFrame but rather in the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method of an object that is derived from JComponent such as a JPanel that is held by and displayed in your JFrame. [Tutorial Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).
- The details of your solution will all depend on the details of your problem.

You ask:

> So if i draw in two paintComponet i can join the two together?

Yep, you could display your image in an ImageIcon held by a JLabel, override JLabel's `paintComponent(Graphics g)`, and draw your lines or whatevers on top of your image. I've got code that does just that somewhere as an answer on this site... will go look.

---

**Edit**
Please check out my answer and code here: [repaint() not calling PaintComponent to use Graphics2D](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14550971/522444).

Comment: So if i draw in two paintComponent i can join the two together?

Comment: Thank you, if you find the code it would be awesome ;)